# Roxy Fileman path changes while saving content

Tags: tinymce, roxy-fileman

when I choose an image with the roxy fileman the image appears in my editor (tinymce 4) and when i check the path of the image its

> (/test/fileman/uploads/image.jpg)

- that's correct, but when I check `$_POST['content']` after the form submit then the image path changes to

> ../../../fileman/uploads/image.png

- how could I changed this path, because this is not correct ... it should be the same as the path before submit.